# How can a "continue" be used to jump back to the beginning of a "do" loop?

Tags: java

Can someone provide a short example of how a "continue" statement can be used to jump back to the beginning of a "do".

Comment: Care to clarify the question?

Comment: By 'beginning' do you mean the first iteration or just the start of the `do` block?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
int i = 0;
do{
    if(i == 5)
        // Won't print 5 but instead go back to the "top" of do
        // but first, will execute the while verification
        continue; 
    System.out.println(i);
}while(i++ < 10);
```

[Example on ideone](http://ideone.com/ILNdx)

Answer (score 3):

A `continue` statement goes to the beginning of the next iteration. You can't go back in the same iteration. See [the docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html).